# MATLAB not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: matlab, ubuntu

I've installed MATLAB for MOOC of Coursera in my laptop running Ubuntu 16.04. The installation route is `/usr/local/MATLAB`. All the installation process is ok, but after I go and try to run it using the command `matlab` on the terminal, it gives me this window:

[image]

And this Error Details:

```
MATLAB crash file:/home/carlosab1802/matlab_crash_dump.15687-1:


------------------------------------------------------------------------
       Segmentation violation detected at Sun Jul 31 12:49:35 2016
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Configuration:
  Crash Decoding      : Disabled
  Crash Mode          : continue (default)
  Current Graphics Driver: Unknown hardware 
  Current Visual      : 0x63 (class 4, depth 24)
  Default Encoding    : UTF-8
  GNU C Library       : 2.23 stable
  Host Name           : carlosab1802
  MATLAB Architecture : glnxa64
  MATLAB Root         : /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a
  MATLAB Version      : 9.0.0.341360 (R2016a)
  OpenGL              : hardware
  Operating System    : Linux 4.4.0-31-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13    00:07:12 UTC 2016 x86_64
  Processor ID        : x86 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
  Virtual Machine     : Java 1.7.0_60-b19 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
  Window System       : The X.Org Foundation (11803000), display :0
If this problem is reproducible, please submit a Service Request via:
http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/
A technical support engineer might contact you with further information.
Thank you for your help.
```

I don't know how to fix it, I've searched a lot and people always say "install matlab-support", I've done it but it still does not work.

Comment: why don't you contact the MATLAB support as the error message suggests?

Comment: Carlos, I won't inline an image that doesn't have an image description; you're supposed to enter that. Also, this is a question about general software usage, not about programming, and I think it would be better suited for superuser, askubuntu or the mathworks forums

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/758892/doesnt-matlab-work-on-ubuntu-16-04. This question has been asked many times in Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common error for Matlab on Ubuntu 15.06 and higher, and on Ubuntu derivated platforms like Kubuntu. I had this error myself also, while using Kubuntu 15. There is a solution on the forum of Mathworks, which I will copy for you here. With this solution I was able to solve the issue:

> Summary
>
> MATLAB crashes during startup on Ubuntu 15.04 and newer, as well as  distributions derived from those versions
>
> Description
>
> When using Ubuntu Linux distributions 15.04 and newer, as well as distributions derived from those versions, MATLAB can crash during startup.
>
> This crash occurs because these releases include a newer version of libstdc++.so.6 than the version shipped with MATLAB (version 6.0.17). When MATLAB loads version 6.0.17 first, the OS reaches an incompatibility that causes MATLAB to crash.
>
> Workaround
>
> You can force MATLAB to load the newer version of the library provided by the operating system, by following these instructions:
>
> Identify the location where MATLAB is installed
> Navigate to the sys/os/glnxa64 directory within this installation folder
> Rename libstdc++.so.6 library to libstdc++.so.6.old
> We have done limited testing with version 20 of libstdc++.so.6. If you experience problems with MATLAB when using this version, please contact MathWorks technical support.

Original post: https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1297894

Comment: This is the solution. I ran into this quite some time ago & there are telltail signs that the issue is a clash with the stdc that is shipped with matlab and that of the system. Within that directory Matlab actually has a readme advising you deal with these files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo apt-get install matlab-support