# Matlab not Working in Ubuntu (LibGL Error)

Tags: matlab, installation, ubuntu-16.04

I downloaded MATLAB from my college's WLAN and installed it on my Ubuntu 16.04 system. But when I run the command `matlab` in the terminal, I get the following error.

> libGL error: pci id for fd 4: ffff:ffff, driver (null)
>
> libGL error: No driver found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: (null)
>
> libGL error: pci id for fd 4: ffff:ffff, driver (null)
>
> License checkout failed.
>
> License Manager Error -15
>
> MATLAB is unable to connect to the license server. 
>   Check that the license manager has been started, and that the MATLAB client machine can communicate with the license server.
>
> Diagnostic Information:
>   Feature: MATLAB 
>   License path:/home/darshan/.matlab/R2015a_licenses:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/licenses/license.dat:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/licenses/network.lic
>
> Licensing error: -15,570. System Error: 115

I tried the solution given in [MATLAB not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38686880/matlab-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) but it did not work. How do I fix this error?

Comment: This is probably something for your college's IT admin to look at.

Comment: Have you installed this on your college network, then tried to use MATLAB on another network? It depends completely how your college is licensing MATLAB, it may be you have to be on the college network to retrieve the correct licenses. Failing that, as Cris says, contact your college's IT dept or MathWorks support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the mistake I had done during installation of Matlab. I had downloaded some file instead of the network.lic file from my college network. Replacing it with the correct network.lic file solved the problem.